# How can I generate a changelog in github without showing tags?

Tags: github-actions, changelog, github-enterprise

I am working on a branching strategy in Github Enterprise, using `mikepenz/release-changelog-builder-action` to generate changelogs when new `main` versions are created. Changes are merged into a `develop` branch first, and when the action generates a changelog, it includes all the tags from the `develop` branch. All we want is to see the changes themselves, grouped by category (feature, fix etc.). Instead we get what you see in the picture. This is a test repo where I pushed one 'bug fix' but as you can see it is very cluttered with unnecessary tags. I have tried to search on Google as well as the action documentation, but either I don't understand it properly or it's not possible. Any help appreciated. This is the default, without a config file. Essentially, I want to remove everything boxed in red.
[image]

Comment: I ran into something similar in the past and change to use [this action instead](https://github.com/dittrichlucas/changelog-generator), which generate the incremental changelog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't appear to have an input for the previous tag (to only show changes since the last version). So I don't think it will be suitable.

Comment: This action basically appends the new features / bugs to the changelog file since the previous/last tag, [here](https://github.com/ZupIT/ritchie-cli/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) is an example of how it was used if you want to have a look (this action updated this file multiple times)

Comment: I think I understand now. What we are looking for is a new changelog for each release, that doesn't show the tags at all, or at least only shows the tags where changes were made. We have main tags and develop tags, but the changelog is made for each main tag, showing the changes since the last main tag. There will be several develop tags in between. So I don't think this will work.

Comment: Got it now as well :) It's quite specific. You may need to implement your own action to make it happens in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for this. The step that generates the changelog saves it as a .md file. So, I wrote a step that uses bash to take out what I don't want before the file is used to create a release. the lines I don't want start with either a single `#` with a space after it, `###`, or `-`. Hopefully this is useful to someone.

```
      - name: Remove clutter from changelog
        id: trim-changelog
        run: |
          cat release_changelog.md | grep -e '^# ' -e ^### -e ^- > trimmed_changelog.md
```